# mvc dropdown list not showing saved data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a 'User details' view where I would like users to be able to edit their details.

All fields are populating as expected except for my Genderchoice list which defaults to 'please select' instead of whatever was saved(male /female).  I had to convert it from a string list to a selectitem list in order to make it display, is this the problem with retrieving the data?  When debugging I can confirm that the data is being saved.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, "BootstrapHorizontalString")
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Gender, "BootstrapHorizontalDropdown", new { list = Model.GenderChoice.Select(m=> new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the controller you are assigning the model value correctly and it's getting returned properly